# Pandas Dataframe With Conditional Rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tam','John','Tom','Mark','Tim'],'Surname':['Jones','James','James','Perez','Desouza'],'ID':['-','-','-','-','-'],'ID1':['-','-','-','-','-']})

df.loc[df.Name.str.startswith('T'),'ID']="Rule 1"
df.loc[df.Surname.str.startswith('J'),'ID1']="Rule 2"
```

"Rule 2" is populated in ID1 ONLY if the ID column already has a value other than "-".

I am struggling with the most efficient way to apply Rule 2 in the ID1 column by first testing whether ID has a value populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can chain new condition with `&` (bitwise and), dont forget for `()`:

```
df.loc[df.Name.str.startswith('T'),'ID']="Rule 1"
df.loc[df.Surname.str.startswith('J') & (df.ID != '-'),'ID1']="Rule 2"
print (df)
       ID     ID1  Name  Surname
0  Rule 1  Rule 2   Tam    Jones
1       -       -  John    James
2  Rule 1  Rule 2   Tom    James
3       -       -  Mark    Perez
4  Rule 1       -   Tim  Desouza
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df.Name.str.startswith('T'),'ID']="Rule 1"
df.loc[df.Surname.str.startswith('J') & df.Name.str.startswith('T'),'ID1']="Rule 2"
print (df)
       ID     ID1  Name  Surname
0  Rule 1  Rule 2   Tam    Jones
1       -       -  John    James
2  Rule 1  Rule 2   Tom    James
3       -       -  Mark    Perez
4  Rule 1       -   Tim  Desouza
```

Comment: I was wondering how I could extend this to n number of rules ?